# Visual Studio 2010 'Reference Paths' not working in project designer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, reference

I have recently transitioned from VS2008 to VS2010.

In VS2008, I could add a directory to the 'Reference Paths' section in the project designer, and could then subsequently add references to any assemblies in that directory to the project by using the 'Add Reference' dialog.

In VS2010, I add a directory to the 'Reference Paths' section in the project designer, but when I open the 'Add Reference' dialog, none of the assemblies in the reference directory are on the list.

I can add the registry key

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\<version>\AssemblyFoldersEx\MyAssemblies]@="<AssemblyLocation>",

which works as intended, allowing me to see the assemblies in the reference directory in the 'Add Reference' dialog. However, I do not want to do this - I should be able to use the project designer's 'Reference Paths' functionality.

Why is this happening, and what can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has never been what reference paths are for.

After adding a reference using "Add Reference", you can set the reference paths as the set of folders to look in for those assemblies. For instance, you can add a reference to C:\Projects\Library\MyLibrary.dll, but then set the reference path to point to C:\Projects\MyLibrary\bin\Debug so that you can use the version of the library that you just built.

Comment: Careful about looking at old links. Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx.

Comment: Perhaps I could word my question better - I am using the 'Reference Path' as you say, but it irks me that VS2010's 'Add Reference' dialog will not ALSO show me those references, while VS2008 will. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx implies VS2010 *should* be behaving as I desire.

Comment: Ah, I am looking at an old link. Thanks!